# Xcode 10 Arabic (RTL) storyboard not gets load

Tags: ios, storyboard, xcode10, ios12

I have multi-language enabled in my project. In previous Xcode versions, it was working perfectly fine but in new Xcode 10, Arabic storyboard is not being loaded.

instead of (Arabic storyboard) views, it's only loading/replacing the Arabic text in LTR(English storyboard) views.

I don't know if its due to the change in New Localization Pattern introduced in Xcode 10, XLIFF?

Or is it a bug in new Xcode?

---

I've also filed a bug report to Apple [44931689](https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=44931689).

Comment: I noticed the same with Spanish. Filed a bug with apple as well.

Comment: Hi, Muhammad Umair, did u find any solution.@DannyBravo

Comment: @ArpitBParekh see my answer, maybe it's helpful.

Comment: Thank you @MuhammadUmair for your timely reply. Actually i have a problem in one of my third party library i need to change from its source code and RTL woked fine simply.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite old, but I think the issue was related to the hardcoded language set in Project Scheme.

Go to `Product` -> `Scheme` -> `Edit Schemes`

OR beside simulator selection click on your project name and select Edit Scheme.

---

Select "**Options**" and check the `app language`, if it's other than "**System Language**" then this issue could occur.

[image]